# Python find the type and Convert "2022-07-12T05:09:39.057266+00:00 "String to date and time

Tags: python, python-datetime

I'm getting `"2022-07-12T05:09:39.057266+00:00"` as a string from the response, I'm not sure which format is this if its ISO 8601 or Zulu. How do I convert this into date time object?

I need to subtract this time from the current time? Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: You changed your input string; why?

Comment: While copying it got missed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: "*ISO 8601 or Zulu*" that's more like apples and pears; ISO 8601 describes date/time formats while "zulu" ("Z") is the military equivalent of UTC

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now() - datetime.fromisoformat("2022-07-12T05:09:39.057266")
```

For the string with a timezone, use the correct timezone for the current time ("+00:00" suggests to use UTC):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

datetime.now(timezone.utc) - datetime.fromisoformat("2022-07-12T05:09:39.057266+00:00")
```

Comment: @Aditya, it's new since Python 3.7. What version do you use? Did you copy-paste the code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fromisoformat` or the explicit format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"`

```
value = "2022-07-12T05:09:39.057266"

result = datetime.fromisoformat(value)
print(result)

result = datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(result)

print(datetime.now() - result)
```

Comment: @Aditya what is you import ? should be `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: @Aditya or do `import sys;print(sys.version)` and tell us your version